# Angular Остановка выполнения программы до ответа сервера

Tags: typescript, angular

Проблема: есть булевое, допускающее null свойство isAuthorized, в конструкторе сервиса отправляется get-запрос на сервер, чтобы получить информацию о пользователе и убедиться, что он авторизован.

```
private _isAuthorized: boolean | null = null;
public get isAuthorized() {
    return this._isAuthorized;
}
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     this.update();
}
async update() {
     try {
         this.data = await this.getUserInfo();
         console.log(this.data.userName);
         this.userName = this.data.userName;
         this._isAuthorized = true;
     }
     catch (err) {
         ...
     }
}
getUserInfo(){
    ...
    return this.http.get<User>(this.url, { headers: header }).toPromise();
}
```

Однако обращение к ствойству isAuthorized может происходить, пока оно еще равно null (то есть пока сервер не ответил).

Comment: Как вы используете этот сервис? Покажите форму/код компонента запроса

Comment: @AlexanderChernin сервис используется в методе canActivate одного из Guard, чтобы получить доступ к компонентам для которых нужно быть авторизированным

Comment: Тогда, кмк, из метода `update` лучше возвращать  `Observable<boolean>`, по пути присвоив isAuthorized результат авторизации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае я делаю следующим образом:

У тебя при авторизации есть три состояния: `авторизован`, `не авторизован` и `в процессе определения`.
Это три разных значения, которые можно сделать в качестве `enum`.

Далее, создаешь поток, например `BehaviorSubject`, в который указываешь в качестве Generic типа - этот `enum`, а в качестве значения по умолчанию - `в процессе определения`.

Забирая значение из этого потока, фильтруй его на значение `в процессе определения`, а `авторизован` и `не авторизован` - в `true` и `false`.

Вот пример:

```
enum AuthorizationStatus { Grant, Deny, Pending }

const status$ = new BehaviorSubject<AuthorizationStatus>(AuthorizationStatus.Pending);

const isAuthorized$ = status$.pipe(
  filter(status => status !== AuthorizationStatus.Pending),
  map(status => status === AuthorizationStatus.Grant),
);
```

Таким образом, каждый раз, когда ты не знаешь, авторизован пользователь или нет, то поток просто не стреляет, а значит выполнение потока останавливается. Далее, как только сервер ответит, меняешь статус на другой и поток сразу же стреляет значением, успешна авторизация или нет. Если же статус известен, то поток сразу вернет `true` или `false`.